# SQL MERGE statement deleting exceptions

Tags: sql, sql-server

The MERGE statement works except for the last section "WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE"
Here is the statement:

```
MERGE INTO [SQDKRTV96].[MERGETEST].[dbo].[users] T
USING [MERGETEST].[dbo].[PS_VIEW] S
ON S.[NAME_AC] = T.[Initialer] 
WHEN MATCHED AND ( 
        T.[Løn nummer] <>   S.[EMPLID] OR
        T.[Fornavn] <>  S.[FIRST_NAME] OR
        T.[Efternavn] <>    S.[LAST_NAME]
        )
THEN UPDATE SET
    T.[Løn nummer] =  S.[EMPLID],
    T.[Fornavn] =    S.[FIRST_NAME],
    T.[Efternavn] =  S.[LAST_NAME]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
THEN INSERT (
    [Løn Nummer],
    [Initialer],
    [Fornavn],
    [Efternavn]
     ) VALUES (
    S.[EMPLID],
    S.[NAME_AC],
    S.[FIRST_NAME],
    S.[LAST_NAME]
    ) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND (T.[Fornavn] NOT LIKE 'key%' OR T.[Fornavn] NOT LIKE 'guest%' OR T.[Fornavn] NOT LIKE 'udlån%' OR T.[Fornavn] NOT LIKE 'vikar%' OR T.[Fornavn] NOT LIKE 'test%')
THEN DELETE;
```

I want the MERGE statement not to delete records with the NOT LIKE keyword defined for them.
But this MERGE statements keeps deleting them, why?
How can I accomplish that they stay?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should use the AND Operator Instead of OR between the NOT LIKEs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The predicate `T.[Fornavn] NOT LIKE 'key%' OR T.[Fornavn] NOT LIKE 'guest%' OR T.[Fornavn] NOT LIKE 'udlån%' OR T.[Fornavn] NOT LIKE 'vikar%' OR T.[Fornavn] NOT LIKE 'test%'` will not filter any rows because each side of the `OR` is mutually exclusive. For example, any `[Fornavn]` starting with "key" will not start with "guest". Thus even rows with a `[Fornavn]` starting with "key" will be brought back despite your `NOT LIKE`. Presumably you want to use `AND` rather than `OR` in this instance.

Comment: Thanks. Great explanation.